# Нужна помощь с JavaScript. Не понимаю объектов. ООП

Tags: javascript, ооп

Изучаю JavaScript (Чистый). Есть следующий код, описывающий класс PersonFactory, а так же есть конструктор:

```js
function PersonFactory(name, surname, year) {
 this.name = name,
 this.surname = surname,
 this.year = year,

 this.sayHello = () => {
  console.log(`Всем привет! Я ${this.name}${this.surname} и я вернусь в ${this.year}!`)
 }
}

const person = new PersonFactory('T-', 800, 2019)

person.sayHello()
```

Мне не понятна запись:

```js
this.sayHello = () => {
  // ...
}
```

Получается, что для этого объекта присваивается sayHello, которому присваивается функция (Пустые скобки. Или что это, если не функция?), потом всё это больше или равно телу функции??? Все пользуются, но не объясняют как.

Comment: Прочитай про стрелочный функции. Всё.  http://jsraccoon.ru/es6-arrow-functions https://habr.com/ru/company/ruvds/blog/428566/   ООП и объекты тут не причём

Comment: А надо бы отличать `=>` от `>=`... А вот первое предложение случайно оказалось правильным.

Comment: И вообще, что-то тут ООП почти не пахнет.

Comment: Может это и не ООП, я просто смотрел урок по нему, там используется стрелочная функция, а так как я о них не знал, то и материал искал не там)